# Geometrically connected but disconnected variety

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

[This](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0361) shows that a connected variety over a field $k$ is can be disconnected after extending the base field. I am wondering is it possible for a geometrically disconnected variety to be disconnected over the ground field. Say something disconnected over $\mathbb R$ but connected over $\mathbb C$. If not how can I prove a geometrically connected variety is always connected?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $X\to\operatorname{Spec} k$ is a $k$-scheme and $k\subset k'$ is a field extension. Write $X_{k'} = X\times_{\operatorname{Spec} k} \operatorname{Spec} k'$. I claim if $X$ is disconnected, then $X_{k'}$ is also disconnected: as $\operatorname{Spec} k' \to \operatorname{Spec} k$ is surjective, $X_{k'}\to X$ is surjective since surjectivity is preserved by base change, so a surjective continuous map $X\to\{0,1\}$ where $\{0,1\}$ has the discrete topology gives a surjective map $X_{k'}\to \{0,1\}$ and we're done.